# During drag, draw outside of widget's area

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, parent, draw

Given an activity with several widgets, I'd like to provide some additional visual feedback during a drag operation.  I have the drag part working, with the default shadow.  In addition, as each widget handles onDrag, I want to draw a bitmap indicator just outside the widget's area.  I figured out how to draw inside the widget's area, but (as expected) it clips anything drawn past its boundries.

My first thought is to use the SurfaceView.  I would have to create one based on the parent, it seems.  As a newbie, this is a lot of work for me to figure out, so I'm hoping someone can validate this approach first.

Another thought is to draw directly on the parent's canvas (if I can figure out how to get the canvas).  I think the drawback to this would be having to "erase" what I've drawn when the marker needs to move.  Might that cause excessive redrawing?

Are there any other ways?  Will I have the same "erase" problem with SurfaceView as with the parent's canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I think one can use getParent recursively till you find the parent representing the space you want to draw in.  I didn't try this because it becomes very dependent on the layout you use.  If you change the layout, you'll probably need to change the code.

Instead, at the top level of the layout, I chose FrameLayout and put my desired layout as a child of that.  As a second child, I put an "empty" view, with transparent background.  FrameLayout will display all children on top of eachother.  So my "empty" view displays on top of my desired layout.  Example:

```
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:MyApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.mockup"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    ... stuff for my desired layout ...
  </TableLayout>

  <com.example.mockup.ActivityView
    android:id="@+id/activity_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@null" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The code was pretty straighforward except for the location calcs.  To be layout independent, I find it best to convert everything to screen coords; otherwise getTop(), getLeft() return values relative to the immediate parent, which may not be the same space you are planning to draw in.  Here's what I did in the widget that initiates the drawing.  First, you need this in your activity:

```
private ActivityView mActivityView ;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // get "activity" view - this covers the whole activity space
  mActivityView = (ActivityView)findViewById (R.id.activity_view);

  // find the widget and give it the activity view
  MyWidget widget = (MyWidget)findViewById (R.id.my_widget);
  widget.setActivityView (mActivityView);
}
```

And you'll need this in the widget - the one that initiates the drawing:

```
public void setActivityView (ActivityView v)
{
  mActivityView = v;
}

public void drawThing (float touchX, float touchY)
// touchX, touchY - location where user is touching, relative to "this" widget.
{
  int[] locScreen = new int[2]; // x,y
  getLocationOnScreen (locScreen);
  int xScreen = locScreen[0] + touchX;
  int yScreen = locScreen[1] + touchY;
  mActivityView.drawThing (xScreen, yScreen);
}
```

and finally, you'll need to do the drawing in ActivityView

```
private int mXThing;
private int mYThing;

@Override
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) 
{
  super.onDraw (canvas);
  ... draw the "thing" using mXThing, mYThing ...
}

void drawThing (int xScreen, int yScreen)
{
  // convert to view coords.
  int[] loc = new int[2]; // x,y
  getLocationOnScreen (loc);
  mXThing = xScreen - loc[0];
  mYThing = yScreen - loc[1];
  invalidate();
}
```

I imagine there are other ways to do this, maybe better.  If anyone has suggestions, please feel free to comment.